# Selecting the Earliest and Latest Dates from a Grouped RDD

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have a grouped RDD of the form (patientID, [Medication]), where Medication is the below case class:

```
case class Medication(patientID: String, date: Date, medicine: String)
```

The RDD is formed by the below line:

```
val grpMeds = medication.groupBy(_.patientID)
```

Where medication is an RDD of the form RDD[Medication].

For each patient, I'm trying to find the earliest and latest dates a particular kind of medicine, "medicine_A," was administered (note that medicine is a method of `case class Medication`). What I'm looking to obtain is an RDD of the format RDD[patientID, earliestDate, latestDate], but can't figure out how to obtain this.

Any help would be hugely appreciated. An example of what the data looks like (obtained from `grpMeds.take(0).foreach(println)`) is shown below.

```
Medication(000961291-01,Tue Jun 21 19:45:00 UTC 2005,Isotonic Saline (0.9%))
Medication(000096430-01,Mon Nov 15 20:45:00 UTC 2010,insulin aspart)
```

Comment: So what's wrong with using `min` and `max`?  Sample data and expected results would be helpful...

Comment: Date is a java.utils.Date function. I don't believe it has a min/max method, but I can use date1.before(date2). Added an example of what `grpMeds.take(0).foreach(println)` returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `groupBy` is a very inefficient way to get there. As a replacement I would recommend using Spark SQL or `reduceByKey`.

For Spark SQL you should convert `medication` to a `DataFrame`:

```
import spark.implicits._  // import sqlContext.implicits._

val medicationDF = medication.toDF
```

and use `groupBy` followed by `agg`:

```
medicationDF.groupBy($"patientID", $"medicine").agg(min($"date"), max($"date"))
```

For this solution `date` should be `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp`.

For `reduceByKey` first you should reshape `medication` to get key composed from `patientId` and `medicine` and value which is a duplicated `date`:

```
val medicationPairs = medication.map(m => 
  ((m.patientID, m.medicine), (m.date, m.date))
)
```

Next `reduceByKey`:

```
medicationPairs.reduceByKey { 
  case ((xMin, xMax), (yMin, yMax)) => (
    if(xMin.before(yMin)) xMin else yMin,
    if(xMax.after(yMax))  xMax else yMax
  )
}
```